# why i can't used array_filter in my hosting?

Tags: php

I generated ol or menus list item and testing work very well in localhost but when I upload to hosting I got errors:

> Parse error: syntax error, unexpected T_FUNCTION

I double checked in my code and in localhost it still work.
Please help what is wrong with my code.

```
   function generate_li($product, $parent = NULL) {

        $li = "";
        $p1 = array_filter($product, function($a)use($parent) {
            return $a['parent_id'] == $parent;
        });
        foreach ($p1 as $p) {

            $inner_li = "";
            $p2 = array_filter($product, function($a)use($p) {
                return $a['parent_id'] == $p['id'];
            });
            if ($p2) {
                $inner_li = $this->generate_li($product, $p['id']);
            }
            $li .= "<li class='dd-item' data-id='" . $p['id'] . "'><div class='dd-handle'>" . $p['text'] . "</div>" . $inner_li . "";
            $li .= '<div class="m3dd-handle"><a href="' . base_url('menu_add/' . $p['id'] . '/' . $p['id']) . '">Add</a></div>';
            $li .= '<div class="mdd-handle"><a href="' . base_url('menu_edit/' . $p['relative']) . '">';
            $li .= '<span class="mclose glyphicon glyphicon-edit"></span></a></div>';
            $li .= '<div class="m2dd-handle"><a onclick="return confirm(' . "'" . 'Are you sure want to delete this item' . "'" . ')" href="' . base_url('menu_delete/' . $p['id']) . '"><span class="mclose glyphicon glyphicon-remove"></span></a></div>';
            $li .= "</li>";
        }
        $ol = "<ol class='dd-list'>" . $li . "</ol>";
        return $ol;
    }
```

Comment: IF: `echo phpversion();` < 5.3  == no anonymous functions for you

Comment: And if your host is running PHP < 5.3.0 then you need to persuade them to upgrade to a supported version, or it's time to change host.... PHP version 7.0.0 is due out in November

Comment: @Mark Baker
But I see they said it beta. So should i used it? if PHP7.0 is beta

Comment: No you shouldn't be using PHP 7.0.0 yet.... I'm merely using the immanence of its release to show just how far out-of-date your ISP is

Comment: So now I will used PHP6

Comment: 5.3 is six years old, you should be on 5.5.x or 5.6.x.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your host is probably running an older version of PHP (less than version 5.3) which doesn't support closures or anonymous functions. Do a `php -v` from the command line or use `echo PHP_VERSION` to confirm the version of PHP running on your webhost.

Since PHP 5.6 is the latest supported of PHP i strongly recommend finding a new host as the version of PHP they are running is obsolete and no longer receiving security patches leaving it vulnerable to attack.

Comment: *older version* Can't we just call it dead? http://php.net/supported-versions.php It's not even supported anymore. + `phpversion()` might be easier than `phpinfo()` to get what OP needs to check :]

Comment: I totally forgot about that function and it's matching constant. Shows you how often I use it. :)

Comment: Yes this function I got from Stackoverflow member that help to solved my problem now I still used it